# Resolve array serialization in JAX RS without Spring

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I need to create a simple REST interface to a database for a data migration.
What I did was generate entity-classes and beans from the database with Netbeans and write some simple REST Services.
Then I ran into the serialization problem with Jettison, where lists with only one element are not serialized as lists.

I have found solutions for this problem that all seem to require Spring to redefine the serialization-provider or reconfigure Jettison's "serializeAsArray" and "arrayKeys".

Is there a way to either use Jackson or configure Jettison without the need for the Spring framework?

Here is the REST service definition:

```
@Path("/reseller")
@Produces({"application/json;charset=utf-8"})
public class ResellerWS {

@EJB
private ResellerFacade reseller;

@Path("/{id}")
@GET
public Reseller get(@PathParam("id") long id)
{
    ResellerReseller result = reseller.find(id);
    return result;
}
```

This is part of the entity that matters. resellerdepartmentList is not serialized as a list with one entry, but only as the entry itself:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "resellerId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Resellerdepartment> resellerdepartmentList;

...

public List<Resellerdepartment> getResellerdepartmentList() {
    return resellerdepartmentList;
}
```

The service is running under a TomEE Plus 1.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to either use Jackson or configure Jettison without the need for the Spring framework?

I strongly advise you to use Jackson instead of Jettison and it doesn't need Spring to be configured.

---

To use Jackson as JSON provider for JAX-RS, add the [`jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers) artifact in your project dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

This module contains the [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html) class, which is the basic implementation of JAX-RS abstractions ([`MessageBodyReader`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) and [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html)) needed for binding JSON content to and from Java objects.

To configure [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) in JAX-RS, you can create a [`ContextResolver`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) implementation. It will be picked up by the [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html):

```java
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        this.mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // Configure as per your needs
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The [`@Provider`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) annotation marks an implementation of an extension interface that should be discoverable by the JAX-RS runtime. Alternatively, you can register the providers in your class that extends [`Application`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html).

Comment: This did the Job, thank you a lot. I also don't use Maven, so I added jackson-annotations, jackson-core, jackson-databind, jackson-jaxrs-json-provider and jackson-jaxrs-base to the project. First I added them to the libs in TomEE which did not work (the Json stayed the same, still have to check why, maybe I forgot one jar or something) then to the project itself. Finally I had to exchange all `@XmlTransient` annotations with `@JsonIgnore`. Et voilá!